# How to install VSCode using SNAP ? ERROR= snap-confine has elevated permissions

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, snapcraft

On Ubuntu 16 Xenial . Trying to install VSCode .

```
dhankar@dhankar2:~$ sudo snap install --classic code
[sudo] password for dhankar: 
error: unknown flag `classic'
dhankar@dhankar2:~$ sudo snap install --code
error: unknown flag `code'
dhankar@dhankar2:~$ sudo snap install code
136.66 MB / 136.66 MB [================================================================================================] 100.00 % 1.68 MB/s 

error: cannot perform the following tasks:

- Make snap "ubuntu-core" available to the system (no state entry for key)
- Mount snap "code" (snap "code" requires classic or confinement override)
dhankar@dhankar2:~$
```

On seeing error - googled , found that snap may not work on/with, certain architectures

```
dhankar@dhankar2:~$ arch
x86_64
dhankar@dhankar2:~$ sudo snap login
```

....Login successful

```
dhankar@dhankar2:~$ sudo snap install code
error: This revision of snap "code" was published using classic confinement and thus may perform
       arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox that snaps are usually confined to,
       which may put your system at risk.

       If you understand and want to proceed repeat the command including --classic.
dhankar@dhankar2:~$ sudo snap install --classic code
Warning: /snap/bin was not found in your $PATH. If you've not restarted your session since you
         installed snapd, try doing that. Please see https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/9469 for more
         details.

code b37e54c9 from Visual Studio Code (vscode*) installed
dhankar@dhankar2:~$ 
dhankar@dhankar2:~$ code .
snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks
dhankar@dhankar2:~$ sudo code .
sudo: code: command not found
dhankar@dhankar2:~$ whereis code
code: /snap/bin/code /snap/bin/code.url-handler
dhankar@dhankar2:~$ 
dhankar@dhankar2:~$ cd /snap/bin/
dhankar@dhankar2:/snap/bin$ ls
code  code.url-handler
```

After googling some more - saw this answer on the snap - forums https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-confine-has-elevated-permissions-and-is-not-confined-but-should-be-refusing-to-continue-to-avoid-permission-escalation-attacks/5557/6. Thus

```
$ code .
snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks
dhankar@dhankar2:~$ sudo cat /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles[
```

there are suggestions to make changes to apparmor profiles / check the entries for ***snap*** within apparmor , done those as seen below . Not sure what effect they are supposed to have.

```
dhankar@dhankar2:~$ sudo cat /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles | grep snap
snap.core.hook.configure (enforce)
dhankar@dhankar2:~$ code .
snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks
dhankar@dhankar2:~$ 
dhankar@dhankar2:~$ snap version
snap    2.41
snapd   2.41
series  16
ubuntu    16.04
kernel 4.4.0-31-generic
```

My ***snap*** version is as seen above . 
thanks